# Induced map on homology by $f\colon S^4 \to S^2 \times S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Show that $$f_* \colon H_4(S^4) \to H_4(S^2 \times S^2)$$ is the zero map for any $f\colon S^4 \to S^2 \times S^2$.

We are working with integral coefficients. I tried applying the naturality of Künneth Theorem, obtaining the following commutative diagram (Tor vanishes)

[image]

But I'm unsure how does the map "?" look, my idea was to use the map $f$ and projection on the two factors, but in this case I'm not able to prove that it is the zero map here. I don't have any other idea on how to compute $f_*$

Comment: It's easier to see the corresponding statement about cohomology: the point is that a generator of $H^4(S^2 \times S^2)$ is given by the cup product of two classes in $H^2$, but $H^2(S^4) = 0$.

Comment: I'll try thinking about that, I don't have a good feeling with the cup product, (it was explained to me 3 days ago). Then passing to homology should be easy?

Comment: Since $H^2(S^4) = 0$ and cup product commutes with pullback, you'll get that the pullback of a generator of $H^4(S^2 \times S^2)$ by $f$ must be 0. But then by definition of the pullback, $f_* = 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you could write $f$ as a composition $S^4 \to S^4 \times S^4 \to S^2 \times S^2$ and then use the naturality of the Künneth isomorphism to show that the induced map $H_4(S^4 \times S^4) \to H_4(S^2 \times S^2)$ is zero.

Comment: @Math536 this seems very similar to what I've in mind, but I've problems in showing that the induced map from $H_4(S^4\times S^4) \to H_4(S^2\times S^2)$  is zero.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the fact that a generator for $H_4(S^2\times S^2)$ is a consequence of the kunneth theorem for cohomology (b/c S^2 is a finite cw) or comes from a more general statement-setting? (Hope the question is meaningful, I'm getting used of these machinery now)

Comment: @Luigi: yes, it follows from the Kunneth theorem.

Comment: @Luigi:You can express the volume element of $S^2\times S^2$ as a wedge product of the volume elements of the two spheres. These pull back to closed 2 forms in $S^4$ that must be exact since $H^2(S^4) = 0$. This is the de Rham equivalent of the cup product argument,

Answer (score 0):

Künneth for products says $H^4(S^2 \times S^2)$ is generated by $s=\pi_X^* x \smile \pi_Y^* y$ where the pis are the projections and $x,y$ generators of the top cohomology of $X$,$Y$ resp. Since cup product is natural, in other words cohomology is a functor to graded rings, we get $$f^*(s) = f^*(\pi_X^* x \smile \pi_Y^* y) = f^*(\pi_X^* x) \smile f^*(\pi_Y^* y) =0 \smile 0 =0$$

since $H^2(S^4)=0$. Now what does that imply for the induced map on homology?

*you could also use that $\pi_4(S^2\times S^2)=\pi_2(S^2)^2=$ only torsion (by Serre). For example by post composing $f$ with a map to $S^4$ which is not trivial on top homology for sure.*